# AngularJS ToDO List Edit error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue in the Edit Part of a Simple Angular Todo App That I created.
My App Adds, deletes and Edits an Entry. I have used AngularJS and BootStrap for this.
The prolem is, when I press edit button, all the entries, get into edit mode instead of the entry that I want to edit.
I am not sure why the in place edit is not working as expected.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="container">
    <h1>My TODO List</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="todo"></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addItem()">Add</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Serial No</th>
            <th>Tasks to be Completed</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>&nbsp</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="todo in todolist">
            <td >{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td ng-hide="todo.selected == true">{{todo.task}}</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" ng-show="todo.selected == true" ng-model="todo.task">
                <button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="todo.selected == true" ng-click="save($index)">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="todo.selected == true" ng-click="cancel($index)">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit($index)" ng-hide="todo.selected == true">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteItem($index)" ng-hide="todo.selected == true">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript Code:

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
    .controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.todolist = [];

        $scope.addItem = function(){
            console.log($scope.todo);
            if($scope.todo === undefined){
                return false ;
            }
            else{

                $scope.todoObj = {};
                $scope.todoObj["task"] = $scope.todo;
                $scope.todoObj["selected"] = false;
                $scope.todolist.push($scope.todoObj);
                $scope.todo = "";
                console.log($scope.todolist);
            }

        }

        $scope.deleteItem = function($index){
            var index =$index;
            $scope.todolist.splice(index,1);
        }


        $scope.edit = function($index){
            for(var i=0; i< $scope.todolist.length; i++)
                if($index == i){

                    $scope.todolist[i].selected = true;
                }
        }


        $scope.save = function($index){
            console.log("saving contact");
            console.log($scope.todolist.length)
            for(var i=0; i< $scope.todolist.length; i++){
                if($index == i){
                    console.log($scope.todolist[$index]);

                    $scope.todolist[i] = `enter code here`angular.copy($scope.todolist[$index]);
                    // $scope.todolist[i] = $scope.todolist[$index];
                    $scope.todolist[i].selected = false;
                    console.log("todo after save",$scope.todolist);
                }
            }

        }


        $scope.cancel = function($index) {
                    for(var i=0; i< $scope.todolist.length; i++){
                    if ($scope.todolist[$index].selected !== false) {
                        $scope.todolist[$index].selected = `enter code here`$scope.todolist[i];
                        $scope.todolist[$index].selected = false;
                }
            }

        };
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting this

```
$scope.editing = $scope.todolist.indexOf(item);
```

All of your ng-repeats are relying on this to hide/show themselves.

```
ng-show="editing"
```

Comment: So how to I ensure that ng-show happens only for the item that needs to be edited?

Comment: That's a little more complicated.  What I would do is have an array of "editable" booleans, and have your repeating element have ID's of 0, 1, 2, etc.  Then you call edit with your ID, it sets the specific "editable" boolean for that ID to true.  You will also want a function to loop through and reset all the editables to false.

Comment: Thanks! I got that. Now I have another problem. Once I edit I have two buttons. Cancel and Save. Save works fine. But when I cancel, if I have made any changes, the changes are visible :(

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!!